# How to serve a website on a linux/apache web server directly from RAM cache?

Tags: linux, memory, website

My server has hundreds of GB of fast ECC RAM. Most of it is not being used. One solution to a faster website is to use an SSD, but a similar solution would be to use the RAM. The problem with SSD is the SSD will burn out. Datacenter SSD are better, but I don't know how much better.

I got the idea from another post to serve cache from the RAM, and then I thought what if I can serve my whole website of static pages (wordpress in this case, but also some of my sites use other CMS), all over RAM to give lightning fast speeds.

I looked it up but I could not find an easy answer to this.

If you're curious, here is the current amount of RAM and my usage (256GB total):

```
# free -m

         total        used        free      shared      buff/cache   available

Mem:     257724       10836       66004     606         180907       231412
```

How can I cache and serve static websites to users on my linux/apache server which is running cpanel and wordpress, directly over RAM for the fastest speeds?

Comment: You could trust the buffer cache to keep copies of file blocks in RAM. There are kernel parameters that help, such as swappiness. Or just set up a RAM disk (tmpfs filesystem) and copy the web site to it.

Comment: I still would like to know the answer to this.

Comment: My answer is: By trusting the buffer cache, or by using tmpfs.

Comment: Why not answer then?

Comment: Because I am not sure it solves your problem.